# Executing a php method when submit is pressed

Tags: php, html, web, submit, forum

Here is my php code, which isn't working:

```
<?php

echo('
<forum>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Previous" name = "Previous"/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Next" name = "Next"/>
</forum>');

if(isset($_POST['Previous']))
    echo("Previous");

if(isset($_POST['Next']))
    echo("Next");

?>
```

When I press the buttons, nothing happens.

Is it possible to do such things in PHP? If not, what would be a good alternative to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. it's `form`, not `forum`
2. if you want it to do post request you need to add method attribute: `<form method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the tag; it's `<form>`, not `<forum>`. You also need to give it a `method` of `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Bizzare, the top two things, and also.. `action="script location"` in the `<form>` tag.

Example;
`<form method="post" action="index.php">`

Answer (score 1):

Some extra recommendations. First, it's good practice to allow HTML to be kept separate from PHP. So I'd start restructuring along these lines - it means your IDE will correctly colourise your HTML syntax.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Previous" name = "Previous"/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Next" name = "Next"/>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Previous']))
{
    echo "Previous";
}

if (isset($_POST['Next']))
{
    echo("Next");
}
?>
```

Note also all `if` statements should have braces - you can get away without them for single-line clauses, but it's [considered by some to be bad practice](http://java.dzone.com/news/omitting-braces-not-just-a-mat). Also, `echo` doesn't need brackets.

Forms are 'get' by default, and in general you should use this mode, unless you are doing a non-repeatable action (such as writing to a file or a database).

Lastly - if you're using POST and doing a write operation, then you should redirect immediately afterwards, to avoid browser warnings when you use the Backwards and Forwards buttons. Search for "idempotent post" for more info.

Comment: "if statements should have braces - you can get away without them for single-line clauses, but it's considered bad practice." - it's not a bad practice, just a matter of style. It's all good as long as you're doing it consistently across the project. For example WordPress style guide suggest omitting them: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Brace_Style.

Comment: _it's not bad practice_ - we disagree about that, but that's cool. I'll change the text to reflect that the point is debatable.

Comment: +1 for the link to why if statement without curly braces is considered a bad practice. very valid point.